# How to insert and get name of multiple users

Tags: ruby, iterator

I am trying to accept the `first_name`, the `middle name`, and the last name of the user and then display the abbreviated first, middle name of the user with the unaltered last name. I've written the following code and managed to get for a single user.

```
h = Hash.new
puts "Enter the first name for user"
h["First_name"] = gets.capitalize
puts "Enter the Middle name for user"
h["Middle_name"] = gets.capitalize
puts "Enter the Last name for user"
h["Last_name"]= gets.capitalize
puts "The name entered is #{h["First_name"][0]}" +
"." + "#{h["Middle_name"][0]}" + "." + "#{h["Last_name"]}"
```

I want this to happen for five users repeatedly, and display all five name at the end. Can any one help me find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole thing in an array (and end the block with `h`):

```
a = Array.new(5) do
  h = Hash.new
  puts "Enter the first name for user"
  h["First_name"] = gets.capitalize
  puts "Enter the Middle name for user"
  h["Middle_name"] = gets.capitalize
  puts "Enter the Last name for user"
  h["Last_name"] = gets.capitalize
  h
end
```

In the end, `a` will have five hashes of the kind you had. You might want to put `chomp` after each `gets` to get rid of the newline character.

You can print each name by iterating over `a`.

```
a.each do |h|
  puts "The name entered is " + h["First_name"][0] +
  "." + h["Middle_name"][0] + "." + h["Last_name"]
end
```

Comment: Yes. Got it...your solution works...Thank you so much @sawa